# CSV file from xml using xslt

Tags: xml, csv, xslt

I am super stuck and I know someone can probably help but I am not sure how to even ask so here goes hope.

End results needed: CSV file from xml using xslt - for each image in the file

"case number","surename","\00000000\231.tif"

here is what I have and you can see I do not get very close. I get the case numbers and sure names and the image file numbers but cant get them to separate by each image.

My xml file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252" ?>
<PFDM_DATAGRP>
  <DGNUMBER>0001</DGNUMBER>
  <DGCOMPNAME>Bbbb</DGCOMPNAME>
  <DGCOMPID>0331</DGCOMPID>
  <PROJECT PROJID="1">
    <NAME>Microfiche</NAME>
    <DOCINDEXFIELDS>
      <DOCINDEXFIELD>
        <NAME>CASE NUMBER</NAME>
        <TYPE>TEXT</TYPE>
        <FORMAT></FORMAT>
        <REQUIRED>0</REQUIRED>
      </DOCINDEXFIELD>
      <DOCINDEXFIELD>
        <NAME>SURNAME</NAME>
        <TYPE>TEXT</TYPE>
        <FORMAT></FORMAT>
        <REQUIRED>0</REQUIRED>
      </DOCINDEXFIELD>
    </DOCINDEXFIELDS>
    <DOCUMENTS>
      <DOCUMENT DOCID="12">
        <DOCINDEXFIELD>
          <NAME>CASE NUMBER</NAME>
          <VALUE>9264</VALUE>
        </DOCINDEXFIELD>
        <DOCINDEXFIELD>
          <NAME>SURNAME</NAME>
          <VALUE>VI</VALUE>
        </DOCINDEXFIELD>
        <DUPEID>0</DUPEID>
        <OBJECT>
          <OBJTYPE>0</OBJTYPE>
          <PAGES>7</PAGES>
          <FILE1>\00000000\231.tif</FILE1>
          <FILE2>\00000000\232.tif</FILE2>
          <FILE3>\00000000\233.tif</FILE3>
          <FILE4>\00000000\234.tif</FILE4>
          <FILE5>\00000000\235.tif</FILE5>
          <FILE6>\00000000\236.tif</FILE6>
          <FILE7>\00000000\237.tif</FILE7>
        </OBJECT>
      </DOCUMENT>
      <DOCUMENT DOCID="13">
        <DOCINDEXFIELD>
          <NAME>CASE NUMBER</NAME>
          <VALUE>9262</VALUE>
        </DOCINDEXFIELD>
        <DOCINDEXFIELD>
          <NAME>SURNAME</NAME>
          <VALUE>HA</VALUE>
        </DOCINDEXFIELD>
        <DUPEID>0</DUPEID>
        <OBJECT>
          <OBJTYPE>0</OBJTYPE>
          <PAGES>47</PAGES>
          <FILE1>\00000000\238.tif</FILE1>
          <FILE2>\00000000\239.tif</FILE2>
          <FILE3>\00000000\240.tif</FILE3>
          <FILE4>\00000000\241.tif</FILE4>
          <FILE5>\00000000\242.tif</FILE5>
          <FILE6>\00000000\243.tif</FILE6>
          <FILE7>\00000000\244.tif</FILE7>
          <FILE8>\00000000\245.tif</FILE8>
          <FILE9>\00000000\246.tif</FILE9>
          <FILE10>\00000000\247.tif</FILE10>
          <FILE11>\00000000\248.tif</FILE11>
          <FILE12>\00000000\249.tif</FILE12>
          <FILE13>\00000000\250.tif</FILE13>
          <FILE14>\00000000\251.tif</FILE14>
          <FILE15>\00000000\252.tif</FILE15>
          <FILE16>\00000000\253.tif</FILE16>
          <FILE17>\00000000\254.tif</FILE17>
          <FILE18>\00000000\255.tif</FILE18>
          <FILE19>\00000000\256.tif</FILE19>
        </OBJECT>
      </DOCUMENT>
      <DOCUMENT DOCID="14">
        <DOCINDEXFIELD>
          <NAME>CASE NUMBER</NAME>
          <VALUE>9260</VALUE>
        </DOCINDEXFIELD>
        <DOCINDEXFIELD>
          <NAME>SURNAME</NAME>
          <VALUE>HA</VALUE>
        </DOCINDEXFIELD>
        <DUPEID>0</DUPEID>
        <OBJECT>
          <OBJTYPE>0</OBJTYPE>
          <PAGES>55</PAGES>
          <FILE1>\00000000\306.tif</FILE1>
          <FILE2>\00000000\307.tif</FILE2>
          <FILE3>\00000000\308.tif</FILE3>
          <FILE4>\00000000\309.tif</FILE4>
          <FILE5>\00000000\310.tif</FILE5>
          <FILE6>\00000000\311.tif</FILE6>
          <FILE7>\00000000\312.tif</FILE7>
          <FILE8>\00000000\313.tif</FILE8>
          <FILE9>\00000000\314.tif</FILE9>
        </OBJECT>
      </DOCUMENT>
      <DOCUMENT DOCID="15">
        <DOCINDEXFIELD>
          <NAME>CASE NUMBER</NAME>
          <VALUE>9254</VALUE>
        </DOCINDEXFIELD>
        <DOCINDEXFIELD>
          <NAME>SURNAME</NAME>
          <VALUE>MO</VALUE>
        </DOCINDEXFIELD>
        <DUPEID>0</DUPEID>
        <OBJECT>
          <OBJTYPE>0</OBJTYPE>
          <PAGES>5</PAGES>
          <FILE1>\00000000\474.tif</FILE1>
          <FILE2>\00000000\475.tif</FILE2>
          <FILE3>\00000000\476.tif</FILE3>
          <FILE4>\00000000\477.tif</FILE4>
          <FILE5>\00000000\478.tif</FILE5>
        </OBJECT>
      </DOCUMENT>
      <DOCUMENT DOCID="16">
        <DOCINDEXFIELD>
          <NAME>CASE NUMBER</NAME>
          <VALUE>9253</VALUE>
        </DOCINDEXFIELD>
        <DOCINDEXFIELD>
          <NAME>SURNAME</NAME>
          <VALUE>IN</VALUE>
        </DOCINDEXFIELD>
        <DUPEID>0</DUPEID>
        <OBJECT>
          <OBJTYPE>0</OBJTYPE>
          <PAGES>22</PAGES>
          <FILE1>\00000000\479.tif</FILE1>
          <FILE2>\00000000\480.tif</FILE2>
          <FILE3>\00000000\481.tif</FILE3>
          <FILE4>\00000000\482.tif</FILE4>
          <FILE5>\00000000\483.tif</FILE5>
          <FILE6>\00000000\484.tif</FILE6>
          <FILE7>\00000000\485.tif</FILE7>
          <FILE8>\00000000\486.tif</FILE8>
          <FILE9>\00000000\487.tif</FILE9>
          <FILE10>\00000000\488.tif</FILE10>
          <FILE11>\00000000\489.tif</FILE11>
          <FILE12>\00000000\490.tif</FILE12>
          <FILE13>\00000000\491.tif</FILE13>
          <FILE14>\00000000\492.tif</FILE14>
          <FILE15>\00000000\493.tif</FILE15>
          <FILE16>\00000000\494.tif</FILE16>
          <FILE17>\00000000\495.tif</FILE17>
          <FILE18>\00000000\496.tif</FILE18>
          <FILE19>\00000000\497.tif</FILE19>
          <FILE20>\00000000\498.tif</FILE20>
          <FILE21>\00000000\499.tif</FILE21>
          <FILE22>\00000000\500.tif</FILE22>
        </OBJECT>
      </DOCUMENT>
      <DOCUMENT DOCID="17">
        <DOCINDEXFIELD>
          <NAME>CASE NUMBER</NAME>
          <VALUE>0831</VALUE>
        </DOCINDEXFIELD>
        <DOCINDEXFIELD>
          <NAME>SURNAME</NAME>
          <VALUE></VALUE>
        </DOCINDEXFIELD>
        <DUPEID>0</DUPEID>
        <OBJECT>
          <OBJTYPE>0</OBJTYPE>
          <PAGES>83</PAGES>
          <FILE1>\00000000\953.tif</FILE1>
          <FILE2>\00000000\954.tif</FILE2>
          <FILE3>\00000000\955.tif</FILE3>
          <FILE4>\00000000\956.tif</FILE4>
          <FILE5>\00000000\957.tif</FILE5>
          <FILE6>\00000000\958.tif</FILE6>
          <FILE7>\00000000\959.tif</FILE7>
          <FILE8>\00000000\960.tif</FILE8>
          <FILE9>\00000000\961.tif</FILE9>
          <FILE10>\00000000\962.tif</FILE10>
          <FILE11>\00000000\963.tif</FILE11>
          <FILE12>\00000000\964.tif</FILE12>
          <FILE13>\00000000\965.tif</FILE13>
          <FILE14>\00000000\966.tif</FILE14>
          <FILE15>\00000000\967.tif</FILE15>
          <FILE16>\00000000\968.tif</FILE16>
          <FILE17>\00000000\969.tif</FILE17>
          <FILE18>\00000000\970.tif</FILE18>
          <FILE19>\00000000\971.tif</FILE19>
          <FILE20>\00000000\972.tif</FILE20>
          <FILE21>\00000000\973.tif</FILE21>
          <FILE22>\00000000\974.tif</FILE22>
          <FILE23>\00000000\975.tif</FILE23>
          <FILE24>\00000000\976.tif</FILE24>
          <FILE25>\00000000\977.tif</FILE25>
          <FILE26>\00000000\978.tif</FILE26>
          <FILE27>\00000000\979.tif</FILE27>
          <FILE28>\00000000\980.tif</FILE28>
          <FILE29>\00000000\981.tif</FILE29>
          <FILE30>\00000000\982.tif</FILE30>
          <FILE31>\00000000\983.tif</FILE31>
          <FILE32>\00000000\984.tif</FILE32>
          <FILE33>\00000000\985.tif</FILE33>
          <FILE34>\00000000\986.tif</FILE34>
          <FILE35>\00000000\987.tif</FILE35>
          <FILE36>\00000000\988.tif</FILE36>
          <FILE37>\00000000\989.tif</FILE37>
          <FILE38>\00000000\990.tif</FILE38>
          <FILE39>\00000000\991.tif</FILE39>
          <FILE40>\00000000\992.tif</FILE40>
          <FILE41>\00000000\993.tif</FILE41>
          <FILE42>\00000000\994.tif</FILE42>
          <FILE43>\00000000\995.tif</FILE43>
          <FILE44>\00000000\996.tif</FILE44>
          <FILE45>\00000000\997.tif</FILE45>
          <FILE46>\00000000\998.tif</FILE46>
          <FILE47>\00000000\999.tif</FILE47>
          <FILE48>\00001000\1000.tif</FILE48>
          <FILE49>\00001000\1001.tif</FILE49>
          <FILE50>\00001000\1002.tif</FILE50>
          <FILE51>\00001000\1003.tif</FILE51>
          <FILE52>\00001000\1004.tif</FILE52>
          <FILE53>\00001000\1005.tif</FILE53>
          <FILE54>\00001000\1006.tif</FILE54>
          <FILE55>\00001000\1007.tif</FILE55>
          <FILE56>\00001000\1008.tif</FILE56>
          <FILE57>\00001000\1009.tif</FILE57>
          <FILE58>\00001000\1010.tif</FILE58>
          <FILE59>\00001000\1011.tif</FILE59>
          <FILE60>\00001000\1012.tif</FILE60>
          <FILE61>\00001000\1013.tif</FILE61>
          <FILE62>\00001000\1014.tif</FILE62>
          <FILE63>\00001000\1015.tif</FILE63>
          <FILE64>\00001000\1016.tif</FILE64>
          <FILE65>\00001000\1017.tif</FILE65>
          <FILE66>\00001000\1018.tif</FILE66>
          <FILE67>\00001000\1019.tif</FILE67>
          <FILE68>\00001000\1020.tif</FILE68>
          <FILE69>\00001000\1021.tif</FILE69>
          <FILE70>\00001000\1022.tif</FILE70>
          <FILE71>\00001000\1023.tif</FILE71>
          <FILE72>\00001000\1024.tif</FILE72>
          <FILE73>\00001000\1025.tif</FILE73>
          <FILE74>\00001000\1026.tif</FILE74>
          <FILE75>\00001000\1027.tif</FILE75>
          <FILE76>\00001000\1028.tif</FILE76>
          <FILE77>\00001000\1029.tif</FILE77>
          <FILE78>\00001000\1030.tif</FILE78>
          <FILE79>\00001000\1031.tif</FILE79>
          <FILE80>\00001000\1032.tif</FILE80>
          <FILE81>\00001000\1033.tif</FILE81>
          <FILE82>\00001000\1034.tif</FILE82>
          <FILE83>\00001000\1035.tif</FILE83>
        </OBJECT>
      </DOCUMENT>
    </DOCUMENTS>
  </PROJECT>
</PFDM_DATAGRP>​
```

And here is my xslt file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
    

<xsl:template match="/">
 <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  
 <xsl:for-each select ="PFDM_DATAGRP/PROJECT/DOCUMENTS/DOCUMENT">
  <xsl:text>&#34;</xsl:text>
   <xsl:value-of select="DOCINDEXFIELD[1]/VALUE"/>
  <xsl:text>&#34;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select ="','"/>
  <xsl:text>&#34;</xsl:text>
   <xsl:value-of select="DOCINDEXFIELD[2]/VALUE"/>
  <xsl:text>&#34;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select ="','"/>  
 </xsl:for-each>
  
    <xsl:for-each select ="PFDM_DATAGRP/PROJECT/DOCUMENTS/DOCUMENT/OBJECT">
  <xsl:text>&#34;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select ="."/>
  <xsl:text>&#34;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:if test ="position() != last()">
  <xsl:value-of select ="','"/>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:for-each>
 
 </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>​
```

Sorry for the mess but I had to just stop and ask for help before I make it worse.
Thank you for even reading this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entirely sure on the requirements, but it seems the problem is that you do not loop on the correct element (each line must reflect a file, does not it?)  What about the following?

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="1.0">

   <xsl:output method="text"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:for-each select="PFDM_DATAGRP/PROJECT/DOCUMENTS/DOCUMENT/OBJECT/*[starts-with(local-name(.), 'FILE')]">
         <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
         <xsl:value-of select="../../DOCINDEXFIELD[1]/NAME"/>
         <xsl:text>","</xsl:text>
         <xsl:value-of select="../../DOCINDEXFIELD[2]/NAME"/>
         <xsl:text>","</xsl:text>
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
         <xsl:text>"&#10;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work for you?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="PFDM_DATAGRP/PROJECT/DOCUMENTS/DOCUMENT">
        <xsl:variable name="case-number" select="DOCINDEXFIELD[NAME='CASE NUMBER']/VALUE" />
        <xsl:variable name="surname" select="DOCINDEXFIELD[NAME='SURNAME']/VALUE" />
        <xsl:for-each select="OBJECT/*[starts-with(name(), 'FILE')]">
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select ="$case-number"/>
            <xsl:text>","</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select ="$surname"/>
            <xsl:text>","</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select ="."/>
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:if test ="position() != last()">
                <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:if test ="position() != last()">
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow that was fast and both gives me what I need with the exception of I needed the value of surename and casenumber not the name. My fault in the way I asked. you guys rock thanks so much. here is what I used because I could understand how to change it.

```html
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="1.0">

   <xsl:output method="text"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:for-each select="PFDM_DATAGRP/PROJECT/DOCUMENTS/DOCUMENT/OBJECT/*[starts-with(local-name(.), 'FILE')]">
         <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
         <xsl:value-of select="../../DOCINDEXFIELD[1]/VALUE"/>
         <xsl:text>","</xsl:text>
         <xsl:value-of select="../../DOCINDEXFIELD[2]/VALUE"/>
         <xsl:text>","</xsl:text>
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
         <xsl:text>"&#10;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>​
```

Comment: "*with the exception of I needed the value of surename and casenumber*" That makes more sense. But in such case I believe you should look for them by name, not by position. It would also be more efficient to put them in variables and avoid the constant lookup - see the edit to my post.